# Terminating multiple node processes start from NPM run script

Tags: node.js, shell, npm

I've got the following for spawning multiple node processes when user `npm start`s:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node calculator.addition/index.js & node calculator.division/index.js & node calculator.multiply/index.js & node calculator.subtract/index.js &"
}
```

This works fine to start multiple node processes but when I command/ctrl c, the processes are still alive. Any ideas how I can correctly exit these processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use [`pm2`](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) to manage your services lifecycle):

```
pm2 start node calculator.addition/index.js --name addition
```

This way you can stop all processes with :

```
pm2 stop all
```

Your scripts section would look like :

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "pm2 stop -s addition division;pm2 delete -s addition division; pm2 start node calculator.addition/index.js -n addition; pm2 start node calculator.division/index.js -n division"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you run it with a node_modlue called [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) that way all processes will run at the same time and it will stop once you tell it to stop.

```
scripts: {
  "start": "concurrently --raw --kill-others \"npm run addition\" \"npm run node2\"",
  "addition": "node calculator.addition/index.js",
  "division": "node calculator.division/index.js",
  ...etc
}
```